# How to add a security group as a member of another security group in Azure AD B2C tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, group-membership

I have 2 security groups in AzureAD(B2C tenant) and I want one to be a member of another group. In the GUI, the group is not found when I try to add a new member. I tried to do this with terraform (via Microsoft Graph) and this fails as well.

Microsoft documentation suggests that this is possible.

Is there something I am missing, or does it require e.g. Premium account (nothing like that is mentioned in the docs)?

Comment: Could you please share more details like screenshots and errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD nested groups is not supported in Azure AD B2C tenant.
[Azure AD B2C tenant nested groups](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/261789a4-f519-4073-a54c-da23714a2f19/azure-ad-b2c-group-memberships?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

However you can add an existing Security group to another existing Security group in regular AzureAD tenant (also known as nested groups), creating a member group (subgroup) and a parent group.

You do not need to have AzureAD Premium account in .

You can add security group into another security group using following steps:

- Select Azure Active Directory, and then select Groups.
- On the Groups - All groups page, search for and open the group that's to become a member of another group
- Go to Group memberships page, select Group memberships, select Add, locate the group you want your group to be a member of, and then choose Select.

Here is a screenshot from my AzureAD
[image]

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-membership-azure-portal#add-a-group-to-another-group

Comment: What permissions do you have in AzureAD?

Comment: I have enough permissions to give myself permissions, but I don't know which one I need :) I tried to add "Directory writers" but it did not help

Comment: May you please check if you assign "Global Administrator" role, your user will have access to "Group memberships" option?

Comment: No, that did not help... I forgot to mention that this tenant is B2C if this makes any difference

Comment: Yes definitely!
Azure AD nested groups is not supported in Azure AD B2C tenant. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/261789a4-f519-4073-a54c-da23714a2f19/azure-ad-b2c-group-memberships?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for help! I have forgotten about it (that it's not vanilla AD) since it looks all the same :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an existing Security group to another existing Security group (also known as nested groups), creating a member group (subgroup) and a parent group. The member group inherits the attributes and properties of the parent group, saving you configuration time.

Currently following scenarios are not supported

1.Adding groups to a group synced with on-premises Active Directory.

2.Adding Security groups to Microsoft 365 groups.

3.Adding Microsoft 365 groups to Security groups or other Microsoft 365 groups.

4.Assigning apps to nested groups.

5.Applying licenses to nested groups.

6.Adding distribution groups in nesting scenarios.

7.Adding security groups as members of mail-enabled security groups

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-membership-azure-portal#to-add-a-group-as-a-member-of-another-group)